# Proper term for electronic-ize(ing) an algorithm

Tags: software, algorithm

Let us consider a certain *computer program* that converts sine values to cosine values:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import math

for _ in range(0, 90, 0.1):
    x = math.sin(_)
    print(  math.cos( math.asin(x) )  )
```

Now, I want to do it *on-chip*/*in-hardware* so I make something like:

[image: sin-to-cos circuit]

So **what is this process of implementing a math algorithm on circuit is called?**

---

Actually, I read Apple's blog

> To achieve long battery life when playing video, mobile devices must decode the video in hardware; decoding it in software uses too much power. <sub><sup>Sir [Steve Jobs](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/)</sup></sub>

and that got me inspired to implement some of my algrothims *in-circuit*. So what is this process called? <sup><sub>here's another [example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71355/implementation-of-aes-algorithm-using-systolic-architecture)</sub></sup>

What do I search for in library- hardwiring, circuitification or what exactly?

Comment: "implementing [the algorithm] in hardware"

Comment: Your software example is doing the algorithm in numbers encoded as binary bits. Your proposed hardware scheme would be processing analog signals. These are not equivalent - just similar functions. Equivalence would have to take into account where the signals are coming from and where the result goes. The two algorithms could only be considered equivalent if one can drop into the larger picture and directly substitute for the other. That said a digital number implementation in an FPGA may come closer to replacing the python example in a larger system scope.

Comment: @MichaelKaras :( but you get the idea, the thing I am trying to say, don't you? I have updated the code & the diagram to better suit what you say, is it correct now?

Comment: You might say that you have 'implemented the cosine function in _analog_ hardware'.

Comment: you essentially want a 90degree phase shift. do you want this at every frequency or just one? can you use a microcontroller, or must it be passive componenets?

Comment: @hassan789 but that ain't my question buddy - its just an illustration. And my algo. is much more complex. What is *the process* called

Comment: Try English stackechange